# Gitlab Pages 502 problem after v13->v14 upgrade

Tags: gitlab

We’ve just upgraded GitLab v13 to v14 and have encountered some problems with our gitlab-pages config. Pages was working fine with v13, but with v14 we are now getting 502 errors when attempting to access the hosted pages.  (We did follow the upgrade path to 13.12.x before upgrading to v14.)

The error seems to be ca-cert/authority related. The last entry in /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-pages/current is

```
{“error”:“failed to connect to internal Pages API: Get “https://gitlab-vm.intranet/api/v4/internal/pages/status”: 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority”,“level”:“warning”,“msg”:“attempted to connect to the API”,“time”:“2021-07-08T10:35:35Z”}
```

Here, gitlab-vm is the server name of the VM hosting gitlab and gitlab-pages, but our pages are accessed at https://project.gitlab-pages.intranet. I diddn’t expect the name of the machine to appear in the api url (in the log entry above), but nevertheless the ‘unknown authority’ rather than a ‘cert not found’ type message would tend to suggest that paths are resolving correctly and that it’s an issue with the ca itself (which was previously working fine).

Has anything changed with regard to how CAs / certs are handled in GitLab v14, in particular w.r.t. the API?

Any pointers to where to start looking to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I've got the same problem. I tried https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html#install-custom-public-certificates, but no luck :(

Comment: Sadly no - pages still not working...

Comment: shucks, keep me posted :D If I get it working I'll post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the update to 14.2.1 (from 14.0.4) the issue with gitlab-pages appears to be fixed.